# R Curve expr parameter

Tags: r, curve

I'm trying to overlay the pdf of an MLE for a distribution and I keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
hist(price, breaks=25, col='light green', freq= FALSE)
curve(dlnorm(price, meanlog = MLE$estimate["meanlog"], sdlog = MLE$estimate["sdlog"]), add=TRUE, col='orange',lwd=3)
```

This gives me the following error:

> Error in curve(dnorm(price, meanlog=MLE$estimate["meanlog"],
>   sdlog=MLE$estimate["sdlog"]), : 'expr' must be a function, or a call
>   or an expression containing 'x'

Comment: `m=3; s=2;
mydlnorm <- function(x) dlnorm(x, meanlog=m, sdlog=s);
curve(mydlnorm) `

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!

Comment: or eventually `curve(dlnorm(x, meanlog = MLE$estimate["meanlog"], sdlog = MLE$estimate["sdlog"])`